# ComboBox DropDown Trigger isn't working after using ToggleButton

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, togglebutton

I have a ComboBox Trigger to open the dropdown when the keyboard focus is on it:

```
<Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True" />
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
</Trigger>
```

It works fine, however after pressing on the toggle button, the dropdown won't work anymore when keyboard has focus on the combobox. The dropdown will still work by clicking on the toggle button thereafter.

Following is the full control template if it helps to answer my question. Thank you for any input!

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                                <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
                                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                            <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                                <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                                                </Canvas>
                                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ScrollViewer>
                                    </Border>
                                </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                            </Popup>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                <ToggleButton.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                                        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                                    <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="#FFACACAC" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                                        <Border.Background>
                                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="0"/>
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1"/>
                                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                        </Border.Background>
                                                        <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                                                            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="F1M0,0L2.667,2.66665 5.3334,0 5.3334,-1.78168 2.6667,0.88501 0,-1.78168 0,0z" Fill="#FF606060" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                        </Border>
                                                    </Border>
                                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="White"/>
                                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFABADB3"/>
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Black"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot">
                                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0"/>
                                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1"/>
                                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                            </Setter>
                                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                                                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                                                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="White"/>
                                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder">
                                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFEBF4FC" Offset="0"/>
                                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1"/>
                                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                            </Setter>
                                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                                                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Black"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot">
                                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDAECFC" Offset="0"/>
                                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1"/>
                                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                            </Setter>
                                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                                                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                                                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="White"/>
                                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder">
                                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDAEBFC" Offset="0"/>
                                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1"/>
                                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                            </Setter>
                                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                                                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#FFBFBFBF"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFF0F0F0"/>
                                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFD9D9D9"/>
                                                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                                                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="White"/>
                                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFBFBFBF"/>
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </ToggleButton.Style>
                            </ToggleButton>
                            <Border x:Name="Border" Background="White" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                    <TextBox.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                                            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
                                            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
                                            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
                                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="Transparent" Focusable="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </TextBox.Style>
                                </TextBox>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Border" Value="0.56"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="False"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: what is Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome ?

Comment: It's from modern ui! https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui